# Alternative to HTTP_REFERER

Tags: http, servlets, reverse-proxy, http-referer

Using [MITRE](https://github.com/mitre/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet), I implemented a reverse proxy. The aim was obviously to open an external Access to one of our internal server. This internal server provides PNG which are embedded within another Website, also served by one of our server. We need to protect this PNGs from "hotlinking" (not sure hotlinking is correctly said -> PNG should be visible only from our Website, and not if the link is opened directly within the browser).

In order to achieve this, we've overridden the execute method of our proxy servlet in order to check if the header contains the "referer" tag, and if not, we return a BasicHttpResponse with 403 code.

In summary, we have:

```
if(!proxyRequest.containsHeader("referer")) {
            HttpResponse basicResponse = new BasicHttpResponse(new ProtocolVersion("HTTP", 1, 1), HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "Forbidden");   
            basicResponse.addHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate");
            basicResponse.addHeader("Prama","no-cache");
            basicResponse.addHeader("Expires","Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT");
            return basicResponse;
        }
```

This seems to work very well. However, after some additional readings, it seems that relying on the "referer" header is not really a best practice ...

Would you do things differently? Which problem do you see with such an approach?

Comment: There are many articles available that talk about the issues with the referrer header.  A [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) goes into a few ways that the referrer isn't available.  But in your code I could send anything for the referrer.  So I'd at least check that it is set to something you expect.

Comment: @stdunbar: yep exactly, in the meantime I updated the code on my side to check that the referer contains couple of "key words". What worries me the most is that it seems proxies are sometimes removing the referer ...